# Which name would have appeared on the Marauder's Map for Lord Voldemort?

Tags: harry-potter, voldemort

Lord Voldemort is known to most of the wizarding world as "Lord Voldemort."

Would he have been named this on the Marauder's Map or would he have been called "Tom Riddle"?

Comment: I'm hoping it would say Tom 'Lord Voldemort' Riddle like a wrestler.

Comment: @ThruGog The Dark Lord Tom Marvolo "You Know Who" "He Who Must Not Be Named" "Lord Voldemort" Riddle

Comment: @Michael - Ironic that someone with so many names should be given the title 'He Who Must Not Be Named.'

Comment: @ThruGog -  I thought it might have been *because* of the too many names :).  He discarded his birth name in favor of "Lord Voldemort" while still young.  Maybe as he grew older, it sounded increasingly ridiculous to him - with no pure-blood lineage and a made up anagram name.  And then what?  He can't go back to his original name, even if he didn't hate it, it sends the wrong message.  And if he picks a new name, he'll just look indecisive - since he's already done the grand renaming thing.  Possibly he forbade everyone from using the name ("for fear") because being nameless was less silly.

Comment: Scabbers showed up as Peter Pettigrew instead of Wormtail, so Voldemort would probably show up as Tom Marvolo Riddle

Comment: @ThruGog, versus Harry 'The Boy Who Lived' Potter. Would make a greate wrestling match

Answer (score 35, accepted):

### Film logic

The map in the film appears to shows the person's chosen name, not their given name. That's why ***Newton*** Scamander's name shows up as ***Newt.***

Presumably "***Lord Voldemort***" would show up with that name, rather than "Tom Riddle."

[image: Marauders' Map--film version]

### Book logic

The map in the book appears to shows the person's given name, not their chosen name. In Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire, Harry spies "***Bartemius*** Crouch" in Moody's rooms. Had it been using Barty Crouch's preferred name, it presumably would have shown up as "**Barty** Crouch".

Presumably "***Tom Riddle***" would show up with that name, rather than "Lord Voldemort".

> *Peeves was not the only thing that was moving. A single dot was
> flitting around a room in the bottom left-hand corner – Snape’s
> office. But the dot wasn’t labelled ‘Severus Snape’ … **it was Bartemius
> Crouch.***
>
> <sub><sup>Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire: CHAPTER TWENTY-FIVE — The Egg and the Eye</sup></sub>

Comment: For film logic, I'm not convinced. "Newton Scamander" was not his canon name at that point that graphic was written. As far as the producers would be concerned, "Newt Scamander" would be his full name.

Comment: @TenthJustice - Indeed. However if we presume that the films are at the same canon level, the fact that one contradicts the other isn't really our problem.

Comment: @TenthJustice - The original Fantastic Beasts charity book contained his full name and was published in 2001, the same year as the release of the very first Potter film.

Comment: @ThruGog - Indeed; https://i.stack.imgur.com/xmTW8.png

Comment: @ThruGog Possibly he was given the name Newt at birth, but then they told everyone it was Newton after the grandmother said she wasn't going to have that name in her family.  So he's Newton (full legal name), Newt (nickname), Newt (real name).  The magic map shows the real name; the Fantastic Beasts the full legal name.  Alternatively, paying attention to this level of consistency in a production like this is like generaitng prophesy from tea leaves.

Comment: Why is Newton Scamander showing at all? Would't he be of old age (and not a teacher)?

Comment: @WoJ - Asked and answered [Why was Newt Scamander's name on the Marauder's map when Fred and George gave it to Harry?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/152386/why-was-newt-scamanders-name-on-the-marauders-map-when-fred-and-george-gave-it).

Comment: @Valorum: thank you (I should have searched instead of posting a knee-jerk question in a comment)

Comment: @Yakk - To your last sentence I say this: You're in the wrong place!

Comment: @Valorum Surely the difference between 'Bartemius' and 'Barty' is the difference between 'Tom' and 'Thomas'. Not that between 'Tom' and 'Voldemort'. I'm not sure your quote proves much more than that the Map doesn't use abbreviations.

Comment: @TheDarkLord - I agree with you insofar as it might say "***Thomas*** Riddle"

Comment: @The Dark Lord - You're the expert, but I've studied you fairly closely and I thought you were actually christened 'Tom' to differentiate you from your father? Not every Tom *has* to be a Thomas.

Comment: And if Barty Crouch Jr announced that he was tired of using "Barty" because that was a kid's name, would the map suddenly switch to "Bartemius"?

Comment: @RichS - I rather suspect that it's whatever name **the magic** feels you're best identified by, noting that magic in Harry Potter is at least semi-sentient.

Comment: @Valorum *"...it's whatever name the magic feels you're best identified by..."* So if Tom Riddle is best identified as "You Know Who", then the map should show "You Know Who".

Comment: @RichS - Ah, but everyone knows that You Know Who means "*ᵛᵒᶫᵈᵉᵐᵒʳᵗ*" :-)

Answer (score 14):

I'll say "Tom Riddle" for one very simple reason: Voldemort was in Hogwarts for an entire year, during which the twins had the Marauder's Map. It's understandable that Fred and George would see the name "Tom Riddle" right next to Quirrell's and not bat an eye [(just like they did with "Peter Pettigrew")](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/33614/why-didnt-the-marauders-map-mark-peter-pettigrew-as-scabbers-when-he-was-in-ra). But "Lord Voldemort" in the castle would HAVE to be noticed.

And as others have pointed out, people like Fake Mad-Eye and transmogrified Sirius and Peter show up under their real names on the map. Hard to see why Voldemort would come up as an alias.

Comment: You're assuming Voldermort would show up when he was attached to Quirrell?

Answer (score 10):

### Tom Riddle

I can't see that the Map would be able to distinguish between someone's birth name and any subsequent aliases that they might've adopted. It is just a map; it has no way of telling what someone likes to be called and no awareness of the huge cultural impact surrounding a name like 'Voldemort'. I don't think the Map cares much for nicknames or aliases; its magic simply writes the first name and surname of each individual, regardless of who that person is or what name others may use to refer to them.

The most telling example we have to demonstrate this is that of Sirius Black. Black also goes by the alias/nickname Padfoot. Yet on the map he is labelled with his full name.

> “And then I saw another dot, moving fast toward you, labelled Sirius Black..."
>   <sub>*(Prisoner of Azkaban, Chapter 17, Cat, Rat and Dog)*.</sub>

If the Marauder's Map was unwilling to ere from its First Name-Surname format for one of its own creators then I doubt that it would do so for anybody else. The natural conclusion is that 'Tom Riddle' would show up on the Map.

Comment: That's his nickname though, not his given name or even his chosen name.

Comment: @Valorum What's the difference between a given name and a nickname as far as the Map is concerned? Do you think the Map can tell how widely used an alias is or how the individual concerned introduces themselves?

Answer (score 3):

With Voldemort, there's more than just the name to consider.  Harry never jumped in panic when he found his own name on the map, so we know the horcruxes didn't register.  Maybe the map only shows complete souls; I'd guess that it can't resolve a soul fragment next to one that's intact.

As to whether the main bit of Voldemort had something the horcruxes didn't, or was "bright" enough to register on the map when nobody was around, I don't know, but I'm sure Voldemort would have made himself unplottable in any case.

Answer (score -1):

He would most likely appear on the map as Lord Voldemort. as user Valorum mentioned, the map in the movie appears to use a person's chosen name, not their given name. Unlike Peter Pettigrew, who was actively trying to hide, nothing about Lord Voldemort's name is him trying to hide from who he is, it is representative of who he is.

Comment: Barty Crouch Jr. showed up as Barty Crouch Jr. in GoF despite the fact that he was impersonating Moody.