# Why don’t the twins notice things on the marauders map?

Tags: harry-potter, marauders-map

Why don’t the twins notice anything?
I mean, come on:

- First year: "Hey, Voldy's balancing on Quirrel's head."
- Second year: "Hey, our sister is going somewhere that doesn’t exist."
- Third year: "Hey, some dead guy and a mass murderer are under the whomping willow, along with our teacher Snape, Harry, Hermione and our brother."
- Fourth year: "Looks like Voldy's in a maze, with the champions."
- Fifth year: "Hey, Harry’s on the train, it looks like he’s stunned."

There are way more. This is the tiniest list. And the same thing with how Lupin could see his friends.

Comment: They gave the map to Harry in Prisoner of Azkaban... so they could have only noticed things in Harry's first two years.

Comment: To clarify, proposed dupe-target is already the dupe-target of _a lot_ of "Why didn't Fred and George/whoever notice Voldemort/Wormtail/etc"

Comment: First year: Voldemort could not be seen as he was possessing Quirrel, he was not running around Hogwarts. Second year, the Chamber of Secrets is unplotted, so if they witnessed Ginny at that time (something unlikely, given that there are hundreds of students in the school), they would see her disappearing in the toilets of the second floor. As for Wormtail, well @Jenayah posted a relevant answer. Pretty much anything after is not true, as they gave the map to Harry.

Comment: Question: for where did it come that Voldemort was physically present in the maze?

Comment: Fourth Year: Harry and Cedric were transported **from** the maze (in Scotland) **to** the Graveyard (most likely in England, a completely different country) - Riddle Jr was never *in* the maze, or within the bounds of the map.

Comment: In the first year, Voldemort might have shown up on the map because it detects ghosts. However, his name would have shown up as Tom Riddle. The scale of the map is really small, so if the names overlapped, he'd probably assume they were talking together. They would probably assume he was talking to a student.  For the second year, the twins didn't have a reason to look for suspicious activity or people. The only times they would have used it were when they were sneaking around and checking to see if corridors would be empty. They wouldn't have been monitoring their sister.

Comment: Voted to reopen. Not every case of someone not seeing something on the map has the same answer. Indeed, in this case, the answer should be that  the premises are incorrect.

Comment: Wasn't "Voldy" in the maze, but Crouch.

Comment: VtR - with the caveat that, once an answer pointing out that the twins didn't *have* the map once they gave it to Harry, I have no objection to it being once again closed as a dupe.

Comment: Another thing to keep in mind is that they weren't always watching the map.

Comment: Thanks @Chronocidal I didn’t understand that part.

Comment: @Skooba: But that just changes the question to *Why didn't Harry/any of the trio notice those things?*.

Comment: Tempted to downvote for lack of research. As Alex's answer demonstrates, the last three questions in particular show a *glaring* lack of knowledge of the books.

Comment: The facts presented in the question are mostly incorrect.

Answer (score 4):

Let's address each of your examples in turn:

- **First year: "Hey, Voldy's balancing on Quirrel's head."**

  We don't know that Voldemort would have even showed up on the map while possessing Quirrel. Additionally, even if he did show up on the map [he might have appeared under the name Tom (Marvolo) Riddle](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/152852/100430) which Fred and George probably wouldn't have recognized.
- **Second year: "Hey, our sister is going somewhere that doesn’t exist."**

  They probably wouldn't know that she was going somewhere that doesn't exist. The Chamber of Secrets wasn't shown on the map, so Ginny just would have been missing during the times that she  was in the Chamber of Secrets. Fred and George would only notice this if they were specifically looking for her and while she was in the Chamber. And even then not being able to find her might not have been so suspicious, given that they might assume that they just couldn't find her among all the other names floating around the castle.
- **Third year: "Hey, some dead guy and a mass murderer are under the whomping willow, along with our teacher Snape, Harry, Hermione and our brother."**

  First of all, Fred and George no longer had the map at this point. They had given it to Harry earlier in the year to enable him to sneak into Hogsmeade. Furthermore, even if they had had the map, and even if they had been looking at it precisely during the altercation in the Shrieking Shack, there wouldn't have been anything to see since the map does not extend that far. As stated in Chapter Seventeen of *Prisoner of Azkaban*:

  > "Where does this tunnel come out?" Hermione asked breathlessly from behind him.
  >
  > "I don't know... It's marked on the Marauder's Map but Fred and George said no one's ever gotten into it.... It goes off the edge of the map, but it looked like it was heading for Hogsmeade..."
- **Fourth year: "Looks like Voldy's in a maze, with the champions."**

  Again, Fred and George no longer had the map at this point. Moreover, Voldy was not in the maze. Voldy was in a graveyard where Harry and Cedric were transported via portkey.
- **Fifth year: "Hey, Harry’s on the train, it looks like he’s stunned."**

  I assume you are referring to the time that Malfoy used the full Body-Bind curse on Harry in Chapter Seven of *Half-Blood Prince* (Sixth Year, not Fifth Year). Once again, Fred and George did not have the map anymore. In fact they weren't even students at Hogwarts anymore, having left towards the end of the previous year. Additionally, the train doesn't ever enter the Hogwarts grounds. As described in the same chapter:

  > Having always traveled there by carriage, Harry had never before appreciated just how far Hogwarts was from Hogsmeade Station.

  Thus, even if Fred and George had had the map at the time, and been looking at it at that precise time, there would have been nothing to see since Harry was off the map.

In conclusion, there seem to be perfectly reasonable explanations for each of your examples, so these examples do not indicate that the twins don't notice anything.